# Need to count the filtered employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a query which need filter out the employee data on behalf on their employee codes.
For instance, in my `XYZ` table i have 200 employees, i need to insert these 200 employee in `ABC` table, but before inserting, i need to check whether all 200 employees are existed in the system,I first filter out the employee and then insert into my `ABC` table.

suppose, 180 out of 200 employee matched, then i will insert 180 in the `ABC` table.
Now i want the count `200-180=20`, so i need that difference count.

I wrote a query but it fetches only the matched record, not those employee count who filters out.

```
Select distinct SD.EMP_code 
FROm SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_012018 SD  /*219 Employees*/
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE) tbl
ON tbl.EMP_CODE=to_char(SD.EMP_CODE)
WHERE SD.REFERENCE_ID like '1-%';

final output : 213 employees
```

I want 219-213=6
i want those `6` employees. I also tried INTERSECT but i got same result.

```
Select distinct to_char(SD.EMP_code) 
FROm SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_012018 SD
WHERE SD.REFERENCE_ID like '1-%'
INTERSECT
SELECT EMP_CODE FROm EMPLOYEE;
```

OUTPUT

```
213 Employees
```

Kindly help me to find out the count of filtered employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT SD.EMP_code 
FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_012018 sd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE e WHERE e.EMP_CODE = TO_CHAR(SD.EMP_CODE)) AND
      SD.REFERENCE_ID LIKE '1-%';
```

Comment: wow, that really works for me, but why you hard code 1 instead of using count

Answer (score 1):

use except opertaor

```
Select distinct to_char(SD.EMP_code) 
FROM SALARY_DETAIL_REPORT_012018 SD
WHERE SD.REFERENCE_ID like '1-%'
except
SELECT EMP_CODE FROm EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: `except` is sql-server.

Comment: thank you so much Vamsi and Anjali, but I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: use minus instead of except operator.